# Fastest way to union a set of polygons in R

Tags: r, polygon, union

I want to find the fastest way to union a set of polygons into one large polygon.

Lets first get some data:

```
# Load libraries
library('raster')
library('geosphere')
library('mapview') 
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)

# Get SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object example
pols<- getData('GADM', country = 'DK', level = 2)

#Project to suitable projection (to be able to calculate area, see later
utm32 = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
pols<- spTransform(pols, CRS(utm32))

mapview(pols)
```

[image]

```
# 1st approach: maptools::unionSpatialPolygons
system.time(pol1 <- unionSpatialPolygons(pols,rep(1, length(pols))))
#  bruger   system forløbet 
#    3.67     0.03     3.72 

# 2nd approach: rgeos::gUnion
system.time(pol2 <- gUnaryUnion(pols, id = pols@data$NAME_0))
#  bruger   system forløbet 
#    3.69     0.00     3.74 

#3rd appraoch: sf:st_union
pols_sf <- st_as_sf(pols)
system.time(pol3 <- st_union(pols_sf))
#  bruger   system forløbet 
#    3.67     0.02     3.68 

# 4th approach: rgeos::gBuffer
system.time(pol4 <- gBuffer(pols, byid=F, width=0))
#  bruger   system forløbet 
#    1.13     0.00     1.16
```

Of the four approaches, the three first is very similar, whereas #4 is significantly faster. My problem is that the polygons are not identical:

```
identical(pol1, pol4)
[1] FALSE
```

And the areas are slightly different:

```
paste(area(pol1))
[1] "43122105144.9307"

paste(area(pol2))
[1] "43122105144.9307"

pol3 <- as(pol3, "Spatial")
paste(area(pol3))
[1] "43122105144.9724"

paste(area(pol4))
[1] "43122105144.9062"
```

Why is this, and is there a reason for using one approach over the other (apart from processing time)?
Also, do you know of any approaches that are faster?

EDIT:

I did some more testing with more polygons, and it seems as method 1-3 only gets slightly slower with larger dataset, whereas method 4 gets very slow.

Comment: I find `pol1` and `pol2` aren't identical either. A fail in `identical` might simply be having the islands in a different order. The difference in area might be the way floating point numbers are being added up, accumulating over millions of points...

Answer (score 3):

As @Spacedman commented, you can attribute those differences between areas to the summary of the floating point. You have equal results at meter level, what it's a good indicator.
To answer to your question I did a bencmark with "almost" your same process but spliting it using pols as "spatialpolygonsdataframe" (st) and "simple feature collection" (sf). With this layer , results are the same as yours:

```
# Load libraries
library(raster)
library(geosphere)
library(mapview) 
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(rbenchmark)
library(dplyr)


# Get SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object example
pols<- getData('GADM', country = 'DK', level = 2)

# Export to gpkg
st_write(st_as_sf(pols),"pols.gpkg")

#Project to suitable projection (to be able to calculate area, see later
utm32 = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
pols<- spTransform(pols, CRS(utm32))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# topo correction (just in case...)
pols.sf <- st_make_valid(st_as_sf(pols))
pols.st <- as_Spatial(pols.sf)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#benchmark sf
benchmark("unionSpatialPolygons" = {st_as_sf(unionSpatialPolygons(as_Spatial(pols.sf),rep(1, nrow(pols.sf))))},
          "gUnaryUnion" = {st_as_sf(gUnaryUnion(as_Spatial(pols.sf), id = pols.sf$NAME_0))},
          "st_union" = {st_union(pols.sf)},
          "gBuffer" = {st_as_sf(gBuffer(as_Spatial(pols.sf), byid=F, width=0))},
          replications = 5,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed")
)

#benchmark st
benchmark("unionSpatialPolygons" = {unionSpatialPolygons(pols.st,rep(1, length(pols.st)))},
          "gUnaryUnion" = {gUnaryUnion(pols.st, id = pols.st@data$NAME_0)},
          "st_union" = {st_union(st_as_sf(pols.st))},
          "gBuffer" = {gBuffer(pols.st, byid=F, width=0)},
          replications = 5,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed")
)
```

These are the results of the original sf layer:

```
                  test replications elapsed
4              gBuffer            5   6.239
2          gUnaryUnion            5  14.528
3             st_union            5  13.866
1 unionSpatialPolygons            5  14.690
```

...and this for the st (your initial process):

```
                  test replications elapsed
4              gBuffer            5   5.956
2          gUnaryUnion            5  14.075
3             st_union            5  13.765
1 unionSpatialPolygons            5  14.115
```

Looking at this, I decided to choose working with sf layers as I'm more familiar with these process. Now I tried the same benchmark with a **complex layer** (I used the [municipalities of Galicia](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z6ccAAA0bsJF918sdV_x6GQeeJGTy2I2?usp=sharing) as they have quite complex polygons in it). Your will find the url in the code. Here is the result:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Large layer union (minicipalities in Galicia)
# get it here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z6ccAAA0bsJF918sdV_x6GQeeJGTy2I2?usp=sharing
layer <- st_read("./data/Concellos.shp")
layer <- st_make_valid(layer)
layer$DISID <- 1

#benchmark sf
benchmark("unionSpatialPolygons" = {st_as_sf(unionSpatialPolygons(as_Spatial(layer),rep(1, nrow(layer))))},
          "gUnaryUnion" = {st_as_sf(gUnaryUnion(as_Spatial(layer), id = layer$DISID))},
          "st_union" = {st_union(layer)},
          "gBuffer" = {st_as_sf(gBuffer(as_Spatial(layer), byid=F, width=0))},
          replications = 5,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed")
)
```

And the results that I didn't expect...

```
                  test replications  elapsed
4              gBuffer            5   93.109
2          gUnaryUnion            5   21.730
3             st_union            5 1310.276
1 unionSpatialPolygons            5   22.011
```

With this large layer, `st_union` is the worst method by far, while `gBuffer` also does a poor performance.

I also tried to do it using a simple summarise but I takes a lot (may be you can try it as well):

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# What about a simple summarise ?
layer$area <- st_area(layer)
merged <-layer %>% summarise(area = sum(area))
mapview(merged)
```

In the end I just want you to show that any of the processes produces the same results:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# THE AREAS ARE THE SAME FOR YOUR DATA ?
# 1st approach: maptools::unionSpatialPolygons
system.time(pol1 <- st_as_sf(unionSpatialPolygons(as_Spatial(pols.sf),rep(1, nrow(pols.sf)))))

# 2nd approach: rgeos::gUnion
system.time(pol2 <- st_as_sf(gUnaryUnion(as_Spatial(pols.sf), id = pols.sf$NAME_0)))

# 3rd appraoch: sf:st_union
system.time(pol3 <- st_union(pols.sf))

# 4th approach: rgeos::gBuffer
system.time(pol4 <- st_as_sf(gBuffer(as_Spatial(pols.sf), byid=F, width=0)))

# Print areas
st_area(pol1); st_area(pol2); st_area(pol3); st_area(pol4)
```

Here the results:

```
43122105145 [m^2]
43122105145 [m^2]
43122105145 [m^2]
43122105145 [m^2]
```

Show results:

```
mapview(pol1)+pol2+pol3+pol4
```

[image]

Comment: One has to wonder about the internal working of the first three functions. The `maptools:unionSpatialPolygons`, `rgeos::gUnaryUnion`, and `sf::gUnion` are all using the GEOS C++ library. In fact, `maptools:unionSpatialPolygons` uses  `rgeos::gUnaryUnion` under the hood. So, in these three functions, there are basically two different ways of calling GEOS, from rgeos and from sf. It is strange that the performance is so different.

Comment: I was using `dplyr::summarize()` on a large (3.5 gb) file with just shy of 1 million polygons to do a dissolve. In the past it took 16 hours. Based on this post I thought I would try using `rgeos::gUnaryUnion()`. When I downloaded the rgeos package it said it would be retired so I tried the new geos package (downloaded from git) and converted my sf object using `geos::as_geos_geometry()` and then did the dissolve using `geos::geos_make_collection() %>% geos::geos_unary_union()` then converted back to sf using `sf::st_as_sf()`. The dissolve using the geos package only took 80 minutes.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans On [this git issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/661) discussing `sf::summarize()` being slow, edzer mentions that "sf uses a single thread, we did some multi-core experiments but so far with unclear conclusions, and reproducible examples are welcome". I wonder if this contributes to the `sf::st_union()` being so slow?